# how to change properties of list tile from its onTap() function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  leading: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    onTap: () {
       // There I want to change title, background color etc
    },
  ),
  title: Text('title'),
  dense: false,
),
```

I want to change properties of list tile from its own onTap()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `StatefulWidget` and call `setState` inside `onTap` 
code snippet

```
class _ListTileCustomState extends State<ListTileCustom> {
  String _title = "title";
  Color _color = Colors.blue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      tileColor: _color,
      leading: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _title = "changed";
              _color = Colors.red;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add)),
      title: Text(_title),
      dense: false,
    );
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListTileCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListTileCustomState createState() => _ListTileCustomState();
}

class _ListTileCustomState extends State<ListTileCustom> {
  String _title = "title";
  Color _color = Colors.blue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      tileColor: _color,
      leading: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _title = "changed";
              _color = Colors.red;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add)),
      title: Text(_title),
      dense: false,
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTileCustom(),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define one variable before `build` a method and use that variable to the title of listtile and when you ontap then change the state using `setState` and It will change the title of your listtie.

```
leading: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    onTap: () {
       setState((){
          title="your text"
       });
    },
  ),
  title: Text(title),
  dense: false,
),
```

here title is variable
and `ListTile` also has property of `onTap`